# Is it possible for another element to act as a proxy for a file input in a web form?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, webforms

I want to be able to drag a file onto any HTML Element and have it behave as if it was dragged onto a file input.

I can sort of do it with something like this:

```html
<label>
    <input type="file">
</label>
```

… and use CSS to increase the `label` and hide the file input:

```css
label {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
input[type="file"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

but that isn’t very flexible.

I have tried using using a different element, which I would prefer, and JavaScript’s drop event and the `eventTransfer` object. I can get the file data, but can’t add it to the file input.

Other solutions tend to us Ajax and send the file directly or to some sort of holding area, but I would like to know whether it is possible to do simply with the file input.

Comment: The SO image upload window allows you to drop an image file into it without displaying a file dialogue, so maybe you could investigate how it works.

Comment: https://medium.com/@codefoxx/easily-drag-drop-images-into-your-project-with-vanilla-javascript-57058f7c3162

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but that appears to upload the pasted file using Imgur, so that’s not what I need. I can do that easily myself.

Comment: But it has to upload the file to imgur first, which is basically the same operation as uploading to your own server.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the link, but again it stops short of adding it to w form. I can already get the dragged image and display it elsewhere.

Comment: I found another site, but it uses AJAX, which is what SO does. Maybe it's not actually possible.

Comment: This is the site: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/drag-drop-file-uploader-vanilla-js/. Have you tried assigning the blob to the `.files[n]` of the hidden file input when dropping?